# Enable/Disbale eclispe rcp editor via menu when clicking on a TreeViewer element

Tags: eclipse, editor, rcp, treeviewer

In my eclipse RCP application I have a TreeViewer from where I can select different editors, for drawing elements, which show up after double clicking. In my top menu I have an option that allows to enable/disbale the drawing. The action for the editors looks like the following:

```
public class EnableEditorAction implements IEditorActionDelegate {

IEditor hallEditor = null;

@Override
public void run(IAction action) {       
    if (hallEditor != null){
        hallEditor.setMachineHallEditMode(true);
    }       
}

@Override
public void setActiveEditor(IAction action, IEditorPart targetEditor) {
    // check for enabled
    boolean bEnabled = false;
    if (targetEditor != null && targetEditor instanceof IMachineHallEditor) {
        hallEditor = (IMachineHallEditor) targetEditor;
        bEnabled = !hallEditor.isMachineHallEditingMode();
    } 
    action.setEnabled(bEnabled);
}

@Override
public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
    if (hallEditor != null) {
        action.setEnabled(!hallEditor.isMachineHallEditingMode());
    }       
}
```

}

The problem I have is that the menu option is only enabled when clicking inside an editor. What i want is to enable the menu option also after clicking on one of the editors in the TreeViewer to the left.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to check if `targetEditor` is **null**, since the action is already hooked to the editor via `plugin.xml`.

Second, I can see that you have an API `isMachineHallEditingMode()`. This should tell you if the left tree is selected, and the action should work properly.

It's **important** to set your action to **always enabled** in the `plugin.xml`. The `Enables for:` parameter should be empty, because enablement handling is done in your `selectionChanged`.

```
public class EnableEditorAction implements IEditorActionDelegate {

     IEditor hallEditor;

     @Override
     public void run(IAction action) {       
          hallEditor.setMachineHallEditMode(true);
     }       

     @Override
     public void setActiveEditor(IAction action, IEditorPart targetEditor) {
          hallEditor = (IMachineHallEditor) targetEditor;
     }

     @Override
     public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
          action.setEnabled(!hallEditor.isMachineHallEditingMode());
     }       
}
```